# Stochastic process conditional on information.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I have a Gaussian process on the form

\begin{align}
X(t) &= X_0 +  \mu(t) + \int_{0}^{t}\sigma(u)dW(u), 
\end{align}
where $W(t)$ is a brownian motion and the initial condition $X(0) = X_0$ is given and $\sigma : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  is a deterministic function.

I want to find the dynamics of $X(t)$ for $t \geq T$ when additionally
\begin{align} 
X(T) = X_t
\end{align}
is known.

My intuition says that as $X(t)$ is an Ito diffusion, it has the Markov property, thus the dynamics conditional on $X(T) = X_T$ shold be 
\begin{align}
X_T + \mu(t) \int_{T}^t \sigma(u)dW(u).
\end{align}

Is this in fact correct? If so, how could this be formalized? Does one appeal to the independent increments of the process?

Comment: is the function $\sigma$ deterministic in your setting ?

Comment: Yes. Edited the original question to clarify.

Comment: You should investigate this paper and the references therein, theorem 3.1 appears to give the solution if $\mu$ is null : https://www.researchgate.net/publication/321306889_Pinned_Diffusions_and_Markov_Bridges

Comment: or this one :https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304414915002434